# MySQL Query - calculate values between multiple tables and group by id

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

i have a players table, a stats table, and an options value table.  examples below

**PLAYERS**

| id | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | smith |
| 2 | joe | smith |

**STATS**

| playerid | round | pass_yd | pass_td | pass_int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 130 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 246 | 2 | 1 |

**OPTIONS_VALUES**

| id | option_name | option_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pass_yd | .04 |
| 2 | pass_td | 6 |
| 3 | pass_int | -2 |

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT s.pass_yd * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'pass_yd') AS pass_yd_pt
    , (SELECT s.pass_td * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'pass_td') AS pass_td_pt
    , (SELECT s.pass_int * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'pass_int') AS pass_int_pt
    , (SELECT s.rush_yd * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'rush_yd') AS rush_yd_pt
    , (SELECT s.rush_td * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'rush_td') AS rush_td_pt
    , (SELECT s.rec * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'rec') AS rec_pt
    , (SELECT s.rec_yd * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'rec_yd') AS rec_yd_pt
    , (SELECT s.rec_td * o.option_value FROM stats AS s, options_values AS o WHERE o.option_name = 'rec_td') AS rec_td_pt
```

If i specify in each SELECT statement what the player_id is, i can get the expected value, all in one row.

What id LIKE to do is to be able to query the full list of players using a GROUP BY statement, but i am having trouble getting to that point.  i feel like im close, but clearly missing a step.

Comment: It would be better if the `stats` table had separate rows for each stat, instead of putting them in columns. Then you could just join `stats` and `option_values` on that column.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the expected GROUP BY outcome would be, based on the sample tables?

Comment: @Barmar so have a table with columns player_id, round, stat_name, stat_value?  I did not consider that.  interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot the `options_values` table into a single row that you can cross join with `stats` to get the appropriate multipliers.

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, s.round, 
    s.pass_yd * o.pass_yd AS pass_yd_pt,
    s.pass_td * o.pass_td AS pass_td_pt,
    ...
FROM players AS p
JOIN stats AS s ON p.id = s.player_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
        MAX(IF(option_name = 'pass_yd', option_value, NULL)) AS pass_yd,
        MAX(IF(option_name = 'pass_td', option_value, NULL)) AS pass_td,
        ...
    FROM options_values) AS o
```

Answer (score 0):

You would try using Common Table Expressions

so as

```
WITH 
    cteStat as (
        select playerid , 'pass_yd' as option_name  , pass_yd as value 
        union 
        select playerid , 'pass_td' as option_name  , pass_td as value 
        union 
        select playerid , 'pass_int' as option_name     , pass_int as value 
    )
```

Then join this with  OPTIONS_VALUES using option_name    column

Comment: This did not work for me, i believe cause MySQL does not allow for WITH statements yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this:

```
SELECT playerid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.option_name = 'pass_yd' 
             THEN s.pass_yd * o.option_value 
             ELSE 0 END) AS pass_yd_pt, 

    SUM(CASE WHEN o.option_name = 'pass_td' 
             THEN s.pass_td * o.option_value 
             ELSE 0 END) AS pass_td_pt,

    SUM(CASE WHEN o.option_name = 'pass_int' 
             THEN s.pass_int * o.option_value 
             ELSE 0 END) AS pass_int_pt 
 FROM stats AS s 
 CROSS JOIN options_values AS o 
 GROUP BY playerid;
```

You do the `CROSS JOIN` (replacing the comma-join you did) only once and a combination of `SUM(CASE ..)` in the `SELECT` with the corresponding conditions.

Demo here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ighbPMv8tbpKnU2hBYkiVz/0